# Operator to find position of a particle in many body system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, polarization

I am reading the following article by Raffaele Resta about modern theory of polarization

> [The quantum-mechanical position operator and the polarization problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9802004)

My question is not about polarization. The author says that for a many-body groud state wavefunction $\Phi_0 (x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_i,\cdots,x_N)$, the position is defined by multiplicative operator
$$\hat{X}=\sum_i^N x_i$$
So the expectation value of the position is $\langle\Phi_0|\hat{X}|\Phi_0\rangle$.

My question is about this formalism. How is this operator defining the position?

Comment: Do the bodies have the same mass? If the answer is YES, then that operator is nothing but the center of mass position up to the factor $1/N$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Yes, they do have the same mass. And the center of mass=COM=$\sum_i^N m_i x_i/\sum m_i =1/N (\sum x_i)$. Got it. But I am still confused that how can COM give expectation value of the position